# TypeError: gapi.auth2 undefined

Tags: google-openid

I went exactly by the instructions for integrating google sign-in:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id

sign-in works, but sign-out gives a javascript error in the line:

> var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

The error is:

> gapi.auth2 undefined

I include the google platform library as instructed:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' async defer></script>
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: I have a quite minimalistic example of using Google drive (which also requires authentication) in javascript. The entire sample is fully contained in a single html page of 170 lines: http://dannyruijters.nl/webtex/googledrive.html
Maybe that helps you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Are signIn and signOut used on the same page?
Div g-signin2 loads and inits gapi.auth2 so it should work as long as those are on the same page.

In case signOut is on separate page, you should manually load and init gapi.auth2 library.

Full example (you have to replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your actual client_id):

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }

    function onLoad() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init();
      });
    }
  </script>
  <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `gapi.load` documented anywhere?  It doesn't appear to be part of the reference material: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Comment: Same sentiments here @MicahZoltu. My wild guess if you have the `<div class="g-signin2"></div>` button on your page (which all the documentation examples) the API will be loaded for you since the button uses that, but for instances where we don't have the button you must tell the `gapi` object which API(s) to load since it encapsulates all of Google's platform APIs (and probably finds it unwise to load all of them)

Comment: thanks for the solution,, i was stuck in this for a long time

Comment: Cool!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That's what i was loooking for.....my signout is on another page..

can we see following?
GoogleUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
        if (GoogleUser.isSignedIn()) 
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "user is signed in already";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no signed in ";
        }

Comment: @Jarosław Gomułka I have used your code ...but when i try to log in again it doesn't ask credentials, it directly log ins in last google account...Why it doent get completely logged out??

Comment: @nick In our project when we added an auth2.disconnect() before the auth2.signOut() we got complete logout, the desired result.

Comment: Can I put the javascript in an external file?

Comment: FIY, assume that for some reason, you reload the page after a user signs in using Google Sign In, then, you need to manually load and init gapi.auth2 library.