# How to manage google sign-in session (Google Sign-In JavaScript client)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-js-client

im trying to implement google sign-in using their new API : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Sign-in and Sign-out work fine. 
My problem is that i dont know how to manage a session on other pages without a server side.

So i tried this code - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state

And it doesnt work well for me. 
I dont want to have the google sign in button in every page. If i remove the "auth2.attachClickHandler.." part the whole code doesnt work.

All i want is to indicate in other pages (not in the page with the google button) if a user is still connected to or not.
Can you help me?

**EDIT:**
I tried the following code suggested in the answers but i get an error that says: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"

Code:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
client_id : 'ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});
auth2.then(function() {
var isSignedIn = auth2.isSignedIn.get();
var currentUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
if (isSignedIn) {
    console.log("signed in");
    // User is signed in.
    // Pass currentUser to onSignIn callback.
 } else {
    console.log("NOT signed in");
    // User is not signed in.
    // call auth2.attachClickHandler
    // or even better call gapi.signin2.render
    }
});
```

Comment: You could retrieve google user data as you show on the link and then store on localstorage. Best if you store this data during X time like thirty minutes. But this is a good aproach, save the user data on localstorage but from my part it will be better always have a backend to do more checks depending in the final app that you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can load gapi.auth2 on all pages and call:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(...);
auth2.then(function() {
  var isSignedIn = auth2.isSignedIn.get();
  var currentUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
  if (isSignedIn) {
    // User is signed in.
    // Pass currentUser to onSignIn callback.
  } else {
    // User is not signed in.
    // call auth2.attachClickHandler
    // or even better call gapi.signin2.render
  }
});
```

In this solution sign in button is displayed only when user is not signed in.

Comment: I will give it a try in the following days and accept this answer if it solves my problem. Thank you

Comment: in the other pages i get errors like "gapi is not defined". Probably because i dont use the button div in them. Any way to avoid using the button?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815870/typeerror-gapi-auth2-undefined/29833065#29833065