# Load gapi.auth2 when VueJs starts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm building a vue js web app with the possibility to connect with user's Google account.

The log in process (front-end and back-end) are working fine: the google sign in button is displayed, user clicks on it and it's avatar is showed, without a page reload.

Now, a user is already logged in and refresh the page. The "visual" problem here is that the request to the back-end is done at the end because I cannot instantiate gapi.auth2 before the vue js component/page is loaded.

I've tried this solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833065/2379208), but I cannot call gapi.auth2 in the main app `data` section:

```
      <script>
          function onLoad() {
           gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            gapi.auth2.init();
              });
          }
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad"></script>
      ...
      <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Main.js:**

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    user: gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get()
```

The error is `TypeError: gapi.auth2 is undefined`

Is it possible to have the information directly, before the whole page is loaded?

Comment: did you try `window.gapi`?

Comment: Just tried but it doen't work

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get()` is an async task for that you can  use the async `created` hook which is triggered on the creation of your instance and there assign the value to your data :

```js
// import gapi from '....'
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  async created() {
    try {
      let res = await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
      this.user = res.data
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  },
  data: {
    user: null,
  }
})
```

and make sure you have imported `gapi` at the top of your script.

Comment: Import gapi from what? I'm loading it in through script tag

Comment: You got it as long as it is defined you don't need to import it.... The code works right  ?

Comment: Actually gapi is undefined if you got `TypeError: gapi.auth2 is undefined´

Comment: Still the same error: gapi.auth2 not defined. I think it's because gapi.auth2 is defined when the google button is initialised